# Twitter Bootstrap: goToByScroll jQuery plugin does not work after initializing collapse plugin?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

**EDIT: I got the scroll to work by taking out one of the jQuery links at the bottom of the page**

**However, now the accordion collapse does not work and expands all the links.**

I took out this one: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

---

I'm having problems with my jQuery plugin that will scroll slowly to an anchor link. It was working before, until I fixed the accordion collapse. I've looked everywhere and I am a beginner with jQuery, and am wondering if I am linking the right files?

I know that my HTML code for the goToByScroll plugin is fine, I think it is just my jQuery links or jQuery code. I had referenced http://www.spydertrap.com/blog/2012/08/user-experience-jquery-smooth-page-anchor-transitions/ for the jQuery scrolling effect.

The code is as follows.

In the head of my document I have:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<!--Le Styles-->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I would like any help with linking with jQuery, since I am basically trying to teach myself. Here is the accordion collapse code:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion1">
        <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#accordion1" data-toggle="collapse" href="#panel1">

                    <h4>Piece Title</h4>

                </a><!--end link heading-->
            </div><!--end accordian heading-->

            <div class="accordion-body collapse in" id="panel1">
                <div class="accordion-inner">

                    <p>Here's some text.Here's some text.Here's some text.Here's some text.                     
                </div><!--end inner accordion-->
            </div><!--end accordion collapse-->
        </div><!--end accordion group-->
</div><!--end accordion complete-->
```

Here's the bottom of my HTML page with the scripts:

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**This one was taken out and the goToByScroll jQuery worked, but not the collapse function:**   `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<!--calls and pauses carousel from sliding-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.carousel').carousel();
        $('.carousel').carousel('pause');
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".collapse").collapse()
    });
</script>

<!--eases transitions between anchors-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function goToByScroll(id){
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(id).offset().top},'slow');
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.nav a').click(function(){
        goToByScroll($(this).attr('href'));
        return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks! And if there is more needed documentation, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

1. In order for the accordion to work, it requires the `jquery` library. [Here](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js)
2. Why do you have two bootstrap scripts:
   `<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>` and `<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bootstrap.js"></script>`? What's the difference between the two? If they are the same, you can just use `bootstrap.min.js` since this is just the minified version of the `bootstap.js`.
3. How come you were able to use the `.animate()`, `.attr()`, `.ready()`, etc. without the `jquery` library?